# How to login to Confluence when kerberos authentication is used programatically

Tags: authentication, soap, single-sign-on, kerberos, confluence

We have Confluence Server 4.1 version installed. It is using AD authentication (Kerberos/Windows Security).

When we enter the confluence server URL in the address bar of browser, then it shows following pop-up windows for entering the credentials.

[image]

Users access Confluence through their local machines when they’re logged onto the domain. They are already logged into the domain, so are not prompted for a login. Users can easily view, add pages in Spaces.

We have followincg C# code to connect to Confluence, but it could not connect.
....

```
ConfluenceSoapServiceService service = new ConfluenceSoapServiceService();     
service.Url = "http://confluence/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v2";     
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true
Token token = service.login(username, password);
```

....
It throws following exception from the last line while calling serviec.login() method:

Error connecting to Confluence server url ''. Please check ServerAddress, Username and Password. System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: com.atlassian.confluence.rpc.AuthenticationFailedException: Attempt to log in user 'null' failed - incorrect username/password combination.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at ConfluenceAPIWebsServiceVersion2.ConfluenceSoapServiceService.login

Remote API (XML-RPC & SOAP) was already enabled. Basically, I wanted to login and get the token - which can be later passed for calling other functions of the soap API.

Could anybody shed some light on how to connect\login to Confluence?

```
Ref: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/7674/does-the-appfusions-kerberos-sso-authenticator-for-confluence-work-with-the-confluence-remote-api
```